# How to make a CORS request in ClojureScript?

Tags: cors, clojurescript

I'm toying around with a demo game and asset preloading. My free test server doesn't allow to store sounds, so I tried to load royalty free sounds over XMLHTttpRequest. I cannot, however, set the `access-control-allow-origin` value.

My sound loader puts the sounds into an asset atom. The relevant part seems to be:

```
(defn load-sound [url]
  (let [request (js/XMLHttpRequest.)]
    (.open request "GET" url true)
    (.setRequestHeader request "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" baseurl)
    (.send request)))
```

...or for the sake of completeness:

```
(defn load-sound [id url]
  (swap! assets #(assoc-in % [:snd id] {:data nil
                                        :ready false}))
  (let [ctx (:audio-ctx @assets)
        request (js/XMLHttpRequest.)]
    (.open request "GET" url true)
    (set! (.-responseType request) "arraybuffer")
    (.setRequestHeader request "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" baseurl)
    (dommy/listen-once! request :load
                        (fn []
                          (.decodeAudioData ctx (.-response request)
                                            (fn [buffer] (swap! assets #(assoc-in % [:snd id] {:data buffer
                                                                                               :ready true})))
                                            (fn []
                                              (asset-error! :snd id)))))
    (dommy/listen-once! request :error (fn []
                                         (asset-error! :snd id)))
    (.send request)))
```

I tried to add `(.setRequestHeader "access-control-allow-origin" baseurl)` before sending the request, but it would still say "CORS-header access-control-allow-origin not set".

When I create the request from the js-console in Firefox, typing the js-code I literally translated from the cljs, it succeeds.

What am I doing wrong?

There's of course also cljs-http, but it won't let me specify the header, either...

Comment: access-control-allow-origin needs to be set on the server serving the resource (the one with the sounds), not in the client code. I'm guessing that your code works in the js console because in that is not a cross-origin context. From your free server, it is though.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the reply - I thought, I'd need to specify it on the client side, too? I requested from another server in the console, too... so how could I not have been cross-origin then?

Comment: If you look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS you'll see that the client requests don't have that header. Do you know for sure that the server you are trying to load data from allows CORS?